# Divi Visual Builder Buggy

Tags: wordpress, divi-theme

After making the mistake to update Divi and the Website didn't worked anymore, I load a Backup from the day before and now the Divi Visual Builder is totally buggy (But the Update isn't installed).

When I try to add or edit a module, the whole divi site vanish.

Anyone has a clue what that could be, or any ideas to fix that?

Divi Version: 3.26.6

WordPress Version: 5.3.2

Answer (score 0):

### I'm afraid it's a problem for at least some time. They are trying to push people to the paid plugin with more enthusiasm than skills. I've updated a Divi theme today, and getting plenty of sporadic but frequent messages:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40960 bytes) in wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/class-et-builder-element.php
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/Testimonial.php

### Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/module/Signup.php on line 1197

A shame, basically, it means "the theme is a mess". At the same time, builder plugin deactivated itself.

So I've restored and "hacked" the version number in the style.css file so it doesn't bother me any more. Builder didn't go up, though. If you only have small updates, you can do them directly from the database by updating "post_content" field. But, I'm going to look for a theme replacement. Once reputation is lost, it's lost.